# Unwanted vertical spacing between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, html, space

I want to lay out a grid by appending divs to `body` and letting them wrap around the screen.  Why am I getting spacing between the rows?  It remains regardless of margin & padding; see below image.

Here is the markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .square {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 80px;
                height: 80px;
                border: black thin solid;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                for( var i=0; i<60; i++ ) {
                    $('body').append( $('<div class="square"></div>') );
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/257081/squares.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's `inline-block`, it's treated like a line of text, so it gets some space between each line. You can alter the `line-height` or `font-size` of the container to fix it (or both, to be on the safe side):

```
body {
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it nice and good

```
body { line-height: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Add `float: left` to your `.square` class.

Refer this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/VdJhp/1/

Comment: Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/techfoobar/VdJhp/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's your display that's doing it.  You have it set to `inline-block`.  Try doing `float: left;` instead.  That took care of it for me.