# Unwanted space between row of inline-block elements and another row

Tags: html, css

It isn't a table, I just used "row" for lack of a better word.

My problem is that I've got a set of `display:inline-block` elements and an element under those, but there's a gap between them. Note that I'm not talking about the space between the inline elements, I'm talking about the space between the row of inline elements and the other element. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339594/unwanted-vertical-spacing-between-divs), setting a `line-height` and `font-size`, but that didn't help at all (which is why it isn't in the code below)

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="letterhead">
        <div class="name"></div><div class="logo"></div><div class="name"></div>
        <div class="subtext"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background:#eee;
    width: 100%;
}
#letterhead {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12rem;
    font: 32px Tahoma;
    color: #777;
    padding: 2rem;
}
    .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 7rem;
        height: 7rem;
        background: #000;
    }
    .name {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 7rem;
        width: calc((100% - 7rem) / 2);
        background: #fff;
    }
    .subtext {
        //position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        top: 9rem;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1rem;
        background: #555;
    }
```

I made a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/69MkQ/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it is because of your `font-size` and `line-height`. Set them to 0 on `#letterhead` and the unwanted white-space will dissapear. You wil have to set your font-size and line-height back on the children of #letterhead if you want to put content in them.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/69MkQ/1/

Comment: Will accept when I can. But I've got another question: how come it works when I apply it to the parent but not the children?

Comment: If you want the parent to float, you put a float on the parent, not on the child element. Same here...

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin:0 -4px 0 0` to your inline-block divs. And everything will be good. To remove space between rows you must set vertical:align:top. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/69MkQ/10/)**

**CSS**

```
.logo {
        ...
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0 -4px 0 0;
        vertical:align:top
        ...
    }
    .name {
        ...
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0 -4px 0 0;
        vertical:align:top
        ...     
    }
```